# change data type sequence String to String

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

my DAL :

```
  def login(username: String,pass :String) =  
        sql"""SELECT AD1SYS.PKG_STC_LOGIN.USER_LOGIN ('#$username','#$pass')FROM DUAL""".as[String]

      def getEmpName(username: String,empName :String) =  
        sql"""SELECT AD1SYS.PKG_STC_LOGIN.GET_EMPL_NAME ('#$username','#$empName') FROM DUAL""".as[(String)]
```

my service :

```
def login(username:String,pass:String): Future[Seq[(String)]] = {
    db.run(DalLogin.login(username, pass))
  }

  def getEmpName(username:String,empName:String): Future[Seq[(String)]] = {
    db.run(DalLogin.getEmpName(username, empName))
  }
```

My Controller :

```
def login = Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
   val username = (request.body \ "username").as[String]
   val pass = (request.body \ "pass").as[String]
   ServiceLogin.login(username, pass).map { data => 
   ServiceLogin.getEmpName(username,data).map(result => 
     Ok(Json.toJson(result.map( p =>
            ModelKodeCabang(p)
        ))
        ))}
      }
```

the result from Service.login is Seq(String) "data", i can't use the Seq(String) for parameter ServiceLogin.getEmpName(username,data).. how to convert Seq(String) to String ??

Comment: `Seq("xxx", "yyy").mkString`  => `xxxyyy`

Comment: Reduce or fold would work too
`Seq("xxx", "yyy").reduce((a, b) => a + b)`